# Generate image for each font on a linux system using Python

Tags: python, linux, fonts, debian, python-imaging-library

I'm looking for a way to list all fonts installed on a linux/Debian system, and then generate images of some strings using these fonts. I'm looking for your advice as I kind of see how to do each part, but not to do both:

1. To list all fonts on a UNIX system, `xlsfonts` can do the trick:

   import os
   list_of_fonts=os.popen("xslfonts").readlines()
2. To render a string into an image using a font, I could use PIL (Python Imaging Library) and the `ImageFont` class.

However, `ImagesFont.load` expects a file name, whereas `xlsfonts` gives a kind of normalized font name, and the correspondence between the two doesn't seems obvious (I tried to search my system for files named as the output of `xlsfonts`, without results).

Does anyone has an idea on how I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using pango, through the pygtk package.  Pango can list fonts and render them.

Answer (score 1):

you best bet is to do a `find` on all the fonts on the system, and then use `ImagesFont.load()` on the results of that list. I don't know where the fonts are on Debian, but they should be in a well known folder you can just do an `os.walk` and then feed the filenames in that way.

Comment: There is the `/usr/share/fonts` path on Debian. But, as I said, it is not obvious that everything is there and in a directly usable form. As an example, `xlsfonts` and several graphical programs return that I have a font named "nimbus roman", but the only file called "Nimbus" is in my home folder and not in that system directory (and not in a ~/.fonts/ folder either, just a regular one). Thus, searching this way is I think not really reliable.

Comment: the file name of the fonts will not necessarily match what xlsfonts shows, also one font file can contain many fonts in some cases.